# Convert Linq-to-SQL to SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

As I'm preparing a stored procedure, how can I do this in a SQL query?

This is my Linq-to-SQL code:

```
var passedContainers = Db.AssessmentContainers.Where(cac => cac.Assessments.All(a =>
        completedContainers.FirstOrDefault(ac => ac.AssessmentId == a.AssessmentId) != null && 
        completedContainers.FirstOrDefault(ac => ac.AssessmentId == a.AssessmentId).Earned));
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your question needs some work so the community can better help you. Take a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and give it another try.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite a bit scarse, but with some guessing I think it could be something like that what you like to achieve:

```
SELECT * FROM AssessmentContainers A
INNER JOIN CompletedContainers C ON A.AssessmentId = C.AssessmentId
WHERE C.Earned = 1;
```

I don't have the full picture yet, but why would you like to do that with a stored procedure? Wouldn't a view be the better choice?